# Restore factory settings

Tags: update, 7.8, nokia-lumia-800

I updated my Nokia Lumia 800 to WP 7.8 (7.10(8858) to be precise) a couple of weeks ago, and the low volume of media playback is really starting to irritate me, to the extent that I even now carry a second phone to serve as an MP3 player. Before installing this update, the media volume of my Nokia was comparable with that other device.

On this basis, I want to revert to 7.5 as I would rather be able to hear music, instead of resizing start screen icons. I have already tried to reset the phone via **Settings > About**. This removed all of my personal data (joy) but did not revert to 7.5. I have also tried resetting using hardware key combinations as described [here](http://www.nokia.com/gb-en/support/product/lumia800/troubleshooting/) but this just does the same thing.

Does anyone know of a way to restore to actual factory settings?

I don't have a backup of 7.5.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to revert back to 7.5 instead of reset settings.

Since it is an update ant a setting I think the only way to revert back is going to Zune and revert to backup it did when you install the update.

Comment: I hope this isn't the only way, as I dont have that backup any more. The upgrade seemed to be successful, and I needed the space.